# How to change Action Mode icon of SherlockActionBar library?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have use SherlockActionBar library in my application ,now i want to change icon of ActionMode .
Below is screen show in which i have high lighted my ActionMode in which i want to set my own icon.

[image]

Please help me to change icon in ActionMode.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You set this in the style resource like so

/res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@android:drawable/your_drawable</item>
</style>
```

/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@android:drawable/your_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Note the missing *android* namespace before *actionModeCloseDrawable* for API < 11 style

Obviously the theme will be different if you are not using actionbarsherlock

Comment: I am not using sherlock theme, i use   <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_done</item> in my theme but its not working please help

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me how to change the color of a seperator in right of done image?

Comment: Can I place `android:actionModeCloseDrawable` in default `styles.xml`?

Answer (score -1):

u can use any icon by placing it in drawable folder

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.nursing);
```

if its the menu icon then try this
//done_hdpi is the done icon i placed it in drawable folder

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Done").setIcon(R.drawable.done_hdpi).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will make help me because what i have use if ActionMode not ActionBar.